# How can I convert String to Controls and Methods?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, methods, controls

I would like to string the output of a control method;
Here is my code, but it doesn't work;

```
        public static string get(string control_name, string method)
        {
            string result = "null";
            foreach (var control_ in Controls) //Foreach a list of contrls
            {
                if ((string)control_.Name == (string)control_name) //Find the control
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Type type = control_.GetType();
                        MethodInfo method_ = type.GetMethod(method);
                        result = (string)method_.Invoke(method, null); 
//Ejecuting and savind the output of the method on a string
                    }
                    catch (Exception EXCEPINFO)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(EXCEPINFO);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

calling function:

```
    form.Text = get("button_1", "Text");
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Text is a Property. So you don't need `GetMethod` but rather `GetProperty`

Comment: The first parameter of `MethodInfo.Invoke` is the object for which you call the method, so here `control_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "Text" is a property of some Controls in WinForm, not a method, you need to refer to `GetProperty` (or use `InvokeMember` with GetProperty binding) in order to read one of its values.

I think the code below should work (but it's untested).

Btw, I wouldn't call a method 'get' since it is a C# keyword.

```
    public static string GetControlPropertyValue(string control_name, string propertyName) {
            string result = null;
            Control ctrl= Controls.FirstOrDefault( c => (c as Control)?.Name == control_name)
            if (ctrl != null) {
                try {
                    var resultRaw = ctrl.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, ctrl, null);
                    result = resultRaw as string;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

    //invocation
    var text = GetControlPropertyValue("button_1", "Text");
```

Comment: `var ctl = Controls.Find("[Control Name]", true).FirstOrDefault(); string value = ctl?.GetType().GetProperty("[Property Name]").GetValue(ctl).ToString();`